# Can't get Flash Player, no app to use for download

Tags: flash, adobe

I have tried to follow all the instruction given in other answers, but when I try to download Flash Player, I get a message to choose app to use for download. I can't find the one people say to use. Help!!!  I need you tube!!!

Answer (score 1):

Open terminal and run

```
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-restricted-extras
```

This includes flash player

Answer (score 1):

Running

```
sudo apt-get install flashplugin-installer
```

in a Terminal should be enough.